# how to manually cache the values of function calls in 10g

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle10g

I have the following code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION slow_function (p_in IN NUMBER)
      RETURN NUMBER
    AS
    BEGIN
      DBMS_LOCK.sleep(1);
      RETURN p_in;
    END;
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cached_lookup_api AS

    FUNCTION get_cached_value (p_id  IN  NUMBER)
      RETURN NUMBER;

    PROCEDURE clear_cache;

    END cached_lookup_api;
    /


    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cached_lookup_api AS

    TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    g_tab           t_tab;
    g_last_use      DATE   := SYSDATE;
    g_max_cache_age NUMBER := 10/(24*60); -- 10 minutes

    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    FUNCTION get_cached_value (p_id  IN  NUMBER)
      RETURN NUMBER AS
      l_value NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      IF (SYSDATE - g_last_use) > g_max_cache_age THEN
        -- Older than 10 minutes. Delete cache.
        g_last_use := SYSDATE;
        clear_cache;
      END IF;

      BEGIN
        l_value := g_tab(p_id);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          -- Call function and cache data.
          l_value := slow_function(p_id);
          g_tab(p_id) := l_value;
      END;

      RETURN l_value;
    END get_cached_value;
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------

    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    PROCEDURE clear_cache AS
    BEGIN
      g_tab.delete;
    END;
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------

END cached_lookup_api;
/
```

I want to pass two parameters "pi_value1" and "pi_value2" both of varchar2 to the function slow_function instead of "p_in".  Is is possible to cache the results with two in parameters in oracle 10g .

the above code works fine with 1 parameter.

Please any one explain?

Comment: Your type t_tab can only contain a list of number-type values. If you want to modify your slow function to use other/more parameters, you will need to adapt the type t_tab.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a two-dimensional array type to cache the values.  Something along the lines of this (omitting the cache expiration code since that isn't changing)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cached_lookup_api 
AS
  TYPE t_pi_value2_tbl IS TABLE OF NUMBER
    INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
  TYPE t_cache IS TABLE OF t_pi_value2_tbl
    INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);

  g_cache t_cache;

  FUNCTION get_cached_value( p_pi_value1 IN VARCHAR2,
                             p_pi_value2 IN VARCHAR2 )
  IS 
  BEGIN
    RETURN g_cache(p_pi_value1)(p_pi_value2);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found
    THEN
      g_cache(p_pi_value1)(p_pi_value2) := slow_function( p_pi_value1, p_pi_value2 );
      RETURN g_cache(p_pi_value1)(p_pi_value2);
  END;
END;
```